# New Relic - how can I get multiple field values in a single REST API query

Tags: rest, monitoring, newrelic

So I'm trying to use New Relic's REST API to get some measurements about my server.

I was able to get values of a single field, using something like:

```
curl -gH "x-api-key:<my key>" 'https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts/<my key>/agents/<my key>/data.json?begin=<begin>&end=<end>&metrics[]=Database/all&field=call_count'
```

Or

```
curl -gH "x-api-key:<my key>" 'https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts/<my key>/agents/<my key>/data.json?begin=<begin>&end=<end>&metrics[]=Database/all&field=calls_per_minute'
```

But I was unable to combine the two queries to something like:

```
curl -gH "x-api-key:<my key>" 'https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts/<my key>/agents/<my key>/data.json?begin=<begin>&end=<end>&metrics[]=Database/all&field=call_count&field=calls_per_minute'
```

Because it always returns only the results of the second field.

Is there a way to perform these two queries in one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a way to do that currently (New Relic is committed to improving our REST API soon). A few calls like threshold_values return an array of different fields, but for calls like the one you're describing you'll need to make two requests.